# Copy S3 Objects With Python and Boto 3 in Same bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm Trying to copy the objects in same bucket one directory to another sub directory.

**Method 1:**

```
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'MY BUCKET NAME',
    'Key': str(source)
}
extra_args = {
    'ACL': 'public-read'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'MY BUCKET NAME', str(destination), extra_args)
```

The Above code raise the Access denied Error.

**Method 2:**

```
"""
S3 delete objects
"""
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
BUCKET = 'MY BUCKET NAME'
PREFIX = str(object)
response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Prefix=PREFIX)
for object in response['Contents']:
    print('Deleting', object['Key'])
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=object['Key'])
```

This one was used for delete the s3 objects. I decided to implement the copy function first after that the second successful method for delete. How can I copy the objects in S3 Same Bucket?

Comment: If you get `Access denied`, maybe you don't have permissions to do this.

Comment: f I don't have permissions the above methods also should be not working right? But Deletion and Creation working fine.

Comment: Copy require `GetObject` permissions I think. Are you able to download the given object or it is also denied?

Comment: Download working Fine @Marcin. Let me check the GetObject permission.